# urllib2 read to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, urllib2

I need to store the content of a site that can be in any language. And I need to be able to search the content for a Unicode string.

I have tried something like:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.urlopen('http://lenta.ru')
content = req.read()
```

The content is a byte stream, so I can search it for a Unicode string.

I need some way that when I do `urlopen` and then read to use the charset from the headers to decode the content and encode it into UTF-8.

Comment: The encoding is done using a function from the urllib library not from urllib2. From http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#headers

Comment: @Macarse this is not the encoding that Vitaly refers to, he is referring to decoding and encoding the actual request context with '[byte string]'.decode('[charset]') and u'[unicode string]'.encode('utf-8'). You are referring to encoding request parameters.

Comment: related: [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

After the operations you performed, you'll see:

```
>>> req.headers['content-type']
'text/html; charset=windows-1251'
```

and so:

```
>>> encoding=req.headers['content-type'].split('charset=')[-1]
>>> ucontent = unicode(content, encoding)
```

`ucontent` is now a Unicode string (of 140655 characters) -- so for example to display a part of it, if your terminal is UTF-8:

```
>>> print ucontent[76:110].encode('utf-8')
<title>Lenta.ru: Главное: </title>
```

and you can search, etc, etc.

Edit: Unicode I/O is usually tricky (this may be what's holding up the original asker) but I'm going to bypass the difficult problem of inputting Unicode strings to an interactive Python interpreter (completely unrelated to the original question) to show how, once a Unicode string IS correctly input (I'm doing it by codepoints -- goofy but not tricky;-), search is absolutely a no-brainer (and thus hopefully the original question has been thoroughly answered).  Again assuming a UTF-8 terminal:

```
>>> x=u'\u0413\u043b\u0430\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0435'
>>> print x.encode('utf-8')
Главное
>>> x in ucontent
True
>>> ucontent.find(x)
93
```

**Note**: Keep in mind that this method may not work for all sites, since some sites only specify character encoding inside the served documents (using http-equiv meta tags, for example).

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the reply.

But if I do:
u'Главное' in ucontent

it returns False.

Is there a better way to do the search?

Comment: How are you inputting that u'...' string? Unicode I/O is tricky, as your terminal AND Python must be on identical wavelengths. Using explicit Unicode codepoints (boring but NOT tricky) works fine, let me edit my answer to show that.

Comment: I am inputing using the console, If I need to do this for a unit test what should I set the coding: to at the top of the file?

Comment: Depends entirely on how your terminal/console's encoding is set up! See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ -- e.g. for utf-8 use the comment # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at file start.

Comment: Using `.split` on the response header to extract the `charset` parameter is cheating. What if there is another parameter after a semicolon?

Comment: As @RolandIllig points out, parsing `content-type` like this is unreliable; besides, Python provides functions to do it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20714761/25507).

Answer (score 10):

To parse `Content-Type` http header, you could use `cgi.parse_header` function:

```
import cgi
import urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen('http://lenta.ru')
_, params = cgi.parse_header(r.headers.get('Content-Type', ''))
encoding = params.get('charset', 'utf-8')
unicode_text = r.read().decode(encoding)
```

Another way to get the charset:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> r = urllib2.urlopen('http://lenta.ru')
>>> r.headers.getparam('charset')
'utf-8'
```

Or in Python 3:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://lenta.ru')
>>> r.headers.get_content_charset()
'utf-8'
```

Character encoding can also be specified inside html document e.g., `<meta charset="utf-8">`.