# How to identify character encoding from website?

Tags: character-encoding, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm getting from a database a list of uris and download them,
removing the stopwords and counting the frequency that the words appears in the webpage,
then trying to save in the mongodb.

**The Problem:**
When I try to save the result in the database I get the error
bson.errors.invalidDocument: the document must be a valid utf-8

it appears to be related to the codes '\xc3someotherstrangewords', '\xe2something'
when I'm processing the webpages I try remove the punctuation, but I can't remove accents because I'll get a wrong word.

**What I already tried**
I've tried identify the char encode through the header from the webpage
I've tried utilize the chardet

utilize the re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z]") and/or unicode(variable,'ascii', 'ignore');
that isn't good for non-English languages because they remove the accents.

**What I want know is:**
anyone know how identify the chars and translate to the right word/encode?
e.g. get this from webpage '\xe2' and translate to 'â'

(English isn't my first language so forgive me)
EDIT: if anyone want see the [source code](https://github.com/raphaeljlps/ProjetoIC/)

Comment: You really want to read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and [Joel on Software on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Without knowing what the encoding was used by the website, this is hard to answer.

Comment: I had seen the Python Unicode Howto before, but thanks, I will look at the Joel article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy to find out the correct character encoding of a website because the information in the header might be wrong. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) does a pretty good job at guessing the character encoding and automatically decodes it to Unicode.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://www.google.de'
fh = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = fh.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# text is a Unicode string 
text = soup.body.get_text()
# encoded_text is a utf-8 string that you can store in mongo
encoded_text = text.encode('utf-8')
```

See also the answers to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495627/how-to-download-any-webpage-with-correct-charset-in-python)

Comment: Well, I think that this solution works, but I found the problem, the wordpunct_tokenize was separeting the chars e.g '\xe2\xc2' into '\xe2', '\xc2'

Comment: well, beautifulsoup was really awesome, and I think that I found the problem, when I was removing the accents the problem appears.