# Using numpy.genfromtxt gives TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, type-conversion, rawbytestring

I have a project in python that is from kaggle.com.  I am having problems reading in the data set.  It has one **csv file**. We need to read it in and put the target and train parts of it in arrays.

Here are the first 3 rows of data set (the target column is the 19th column and the features are the first 18 columns):

```
user    gender  age how_tall_in_meters  weight  body_mass_index x1  
debora  Woman   46  1.62    75  28.6    -3  
debora  Woman   46  1.62    75  28.6    -3
```

The target column which is not shown here has string values.

```
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient import SGDClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

#d = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={'A': np.str(), 'B': np.str(), 'S': np.str()})

dataset = np.genfromtxt(open('data.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
target = np.array([x[19] for x in dataset])
train = np.array([x[1:] for x in dataset])

print(target)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\Project - Machine learning\datafilesforproj\SGD_classifier.py", line 12, in <module>
    dataset = np.genfromtxt(open('data.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1380, in genfromtxt
    first_values = split_line(first_line)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_iotools.py", line 217, in _delimited_splitter
    line = line.split(self.comments)[0]
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Please take some time to format the code properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python3 Error: TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699362/python3-error-typeerror-cant-convert-bytes-object-to-str-implicitly)

Comment: Also, try to come up with a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your problem has nothing to do with Kaggle.com.  And you should try to cut your program down to 2 lines to isolate the problem.  Also, create an exteremely simple .csv file to practice with.

Comment: @CoDEmanX No it's not. This is numpy-specific, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was changing the line

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt(open('data.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
```

to

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
```

(unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what the underlying problem was)

Comment: did not help at all...
Same file as the OP, this is the content of "dataset": [nan, nan]

Answer (score 3):

This is in fact a bug in numpy, cf. [issue #3184](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3184).

I'll just copy the workaround that I presented over there:

```
import functools
import io
import numpy as np
import sys

genfromtxt_old = np.genfromtxt
@functools.wraps(genfromtxt_old)
def genfromtxt_py3_fixed(f, encoding="utf-8", *args, **kwargs):
  if isinstance(f, io.TextIOBase):
    if hasattr(f, "buffer") and hasattr(f.buffer, "raw") and \
    isinstance(f.buffer.raw, io.FileIO):
      # Best case: get underlying FileIO stream (binary!) and use that
      fb = f.buffer.raw
      # Reset cursor on the underlying object to match that on wrapper
      fb.seek(f.tell())
      result = genfromtxt_old(fb, *args, **kwargs)
      # Reset cursor on wrapper to match that of the underlying object
      f.seek(fb.tell())
    else:
      # Not very good but works: Put entire contents into BytesIO object,
      # otherwise same ideas as above
      old_cursor_pos = f.tell()
      fb = io.BytesIO(bytes(f.read(), encoding=encoding))
      result = genfromtxt_old(fb, *args, **kwargs)
      f.seek(old_cursor_pos + fb.tell())
  else:
    result = genfromtxt_old(f, *args, **kwargs)
  return result

if sys.version_info >= (3,):
  np.genfromtxt = genfromtxt_py3_fixed
```

After putting this at the top of your code, you can just use `np.genfromtxt` again and it should work fine in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-April/622487.html
you probably need

```
import io
import sys
inpstream = io.open('data.csv','rb')
dataset = np.genfromtxt(inpstream, delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
```

In the examples shown in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html
the objects used as file are of class `StringIO`.
Nevertheless, from the specification of the function, I guess that passing the file name should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the `bytes` object to a `str` object explicitly, as the `TypeError` implies.

```
# For instance, interpret as UTF-8 (depends on your source)
self.comments = self.comments.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The code in question is inside the numpy library. Are you suggesting it's a numpy bug? If so, please edit your answer to clarify this.

Comment: Agreed, I am running the first example from here, and that's the same error: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt(open('data.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
```

try this:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt('C:\\\\..\\\\..\\\train.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='None')[1:]
```

Note that you have to use an extra '\' to escape the other.