# Python 3 error: TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly in string that has more than 3 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I wanted to make SHA256 hasher that will save both input and output in text file. I searched stackoverflow for answers but it didn't work. I wanted it to write in the text file:

```
all = str("At: " + date + " you have encrypted: " + text + " into:" + hex_dig)
text_file.write(together)
```

While the date looks like that:

```
date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

It gave me this error in the first line of my sample: `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 Error: TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699362/python3-error-typeerror-cant-convert-bytes-object-to-str-implicitly)

Comment: It' would be really useful if you could post more of your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
all = "At: %s you have encrypted: %s into: %s" % (date, text, hex_dig)
text_file.write(all)
```

Comment: the `str` call around  `hex_dig` is redundant if you're using a `%s` format.

Comment: Is there a b'your_data_here' around your hash though?

Comment: @LexyStardust I think digests get generated as byte arrays rather than strings

Comment: In Py3k (assuming they're using hashlib) the digest function returns a bytes; hexdigest returns a string (https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) I was assuming from the variable name chosen that it was hexdigest that was called (though with so little code to go on, that was only a guess).

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that `hex_dig` is a bytes object (did you use `digest` rather than `hexdigest` to get the hash perhaps?). If that's the case, simply using the right function will sort this out:

```
sha256_hasher = hashlib.sha256()
sha256_hasher.update(your_data_goes_here)
hex_dig = sha256_hasher.hexdigest()
```

Otheriwse, and more generally, you're trying to concatenate `str`s and `bytes` objects together. You can't do that. You need to convert the bytes object to a string. If it just contains text data you can decode it:

```
hex_dig = hex_dig.decode("ascii")
```

Or, if it just contains bytes and you want to see the hex you can use `binascii.hexlify` (you'll still need to `decode` as it returns a bytes):

```
import binascii
hex_dig = binascii.hexlify(hex_dig).decode("ascii")
```

As an aside, you don't need to wrap a string in the `str` function call, you only need that if you want to get the string representation of an object that isn't already a string. What you have (or what you want) is already a string so it's a redundant call. You can't try to concatenate things of different types and wrap all that in a `str` cal and hope python will sort it out for you - it won't (and shouldn't as it's ambiguous - `explicit is better than implicit`).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the `format` method for cases like this.

You wrote:

```
all = str("At: " + date + " you have encrypted: " + text + " into:" + hex_dig)
```

In `format` syntax, it would look like this:

```
all = "At: {} you have encrypted: {} into:{}".format(date,text,hex_dig)
```

The brilliant thing about `format` is that it handles conversion of various data types to string (usually) with great ease.

Hint: you can set your `{}` with `{0} {1} {2}`, etc. if you want to specify which order and/or repeat place holders.