# TypeError - Can't convert 'User' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have a code which was working great on python 2.7 but then I migrated to python 3.5 and it's not working anymore, I'm getting an error.
Here is the code:

```
def gen_cert(keyname, certname, password, username):
cmd = [
    'openssl', 'pkcs12', '-name', username, '-inkey', tempdirname + keyname,
    '-in', tempdirname + certname, '-export', '-out',
    dirname + username + '.p12', '-password', 'pass:' + password
]
s = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False)
out, err = s.communicate('\n'.encode())
```

The error is - `Can't convert 'User' object to str implicitly`

The error is coming due to this `dirname + username + '.p12'`

Here are the local variables:

```
| Variable | Value           |
______________________________
| certname |'w0ui8t9mkg.pem' |
| keyname  |'7g89utc1it.pem' |
| password |'bo02qm99ui'     |
| username |<User: abcuser>|
```

Here is the function which is calling the above function:

```
def generate_user_certificate(self, request, queryset):
    check_folders(request)
    UsersList = []

    for qs in queryset:
        username = qs.username
        keyname = random_name('.pem')
        certname = random_name('.pem')
        password = random_name('')
        gen_cert(keyname, certname, password, username)

        UsersList.append(username)

    # Displaying success message for certificate generation
    allusers = ', '.join(UsersList)
    messages.success(
        request,
        "Certificates for users: " + allusers + " generated successfully.")
```

Also I'm getting an error in `allusers = ', '.join(UsersList)`
which says `sequence item 0: expected str instance, User found`

How to resolve it?
I'm using django 2.0

Comment: I guess username is an User object?

Comment: show the code whre is `username`

Comment: yes username is an User object.

Comment: Can you include the code for where the `gen_cert()` function is called? And possibly the code for the `User` class, if possible.

Comment: @RishabhChaudhary I updated my answer for Django 2.0, although it would still be helpful to see the place where `gen_cert()` is being called in your code. It's python so I know it's not a compile time error ;)

Comment: @LukeBaumann I've added the function which is calling the above function along with the list of local variables for ease.

Comment: @RishabhChaudhary in case those are your real certificate name and password, you should take them down and also change your actual cert file name and password (you can just use a placeholder like `[password]` when asking questions here).

Comment: @LukeBaumann I've updated those cert names and passwords, I'll keep that in mind, to use placeholders. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the errors got resolved when you change this:

```
for qs in queryset:
        username = qs.username
```

to this:

```
for qs in queryset:
        username = str(qs.username)
```

that is instead of `username = qs.username` use `username = str(qs.username)` this converts `username` to `str` and hence no conversion is required at later stage after calling the `gen_cert` function.

So this helped resolve both the errors.

Thanks everyone for your answers and suggestions, they helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

**Brief suggestion:**
What's going on is that `qs.username` is pointing to a `User` object, but you want it to be pointing to a string (namely, the username for that `User` object). In addition to the fixes below, I would recommend that you try to change the key in the queryset. Right now you have the key `username` pointing to something that isn't a username, which is confusing (although you don't need to do this to get your code to work; it's just a stylistic suggestion).

**How to resolve the errors:**
Assuming you're using the default Django.contrib.auth User model, you can access the username with `User.get_username()`. The `str(username)` approach that I recommended before would also work, as that calls the `__str__()` function on the `User` object, which returns the username by default. It would be best to call either method when you call `gen_cert()`, by setting the `username` variable like:

```
username = qs.username.get_username()
```

or

```
username = str(qs.username)
```

For your second question about the `allusers = ', '.join(UsersList)`, I think you're having the same issue, which will be resolved once the `username` variable actually points to a string, and not a `User` object.

Comment: As per your suggestion I've used `str(username)` and it works. But I've used it here:
`for qs in queryset:
        username = str(qs.username)
        keyname = random_name('.pem')
        certname = random_name('.pem')
        password = random_name('')
        gen_cert(keyname, certname, password, username)`
This even resolved the 2nd error.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I guess `str(User)` does return the username of the `User` object. I'm glad to know you've resolved the errors :) The one minor thing I would add is that, right now, your variable `qs.username`, (that is, the `username` entry associated with each element in `queryset`) is really pointing to a `User` object, which is not strictly a *username* (a username is a string, which is just one property each `User` object has). This is just a stylistic issue, but if I were writing this code I would be worried about getting confused if I had the key `username` pointing to a `User` object.

Comment: @RishabhChaudhary I updated my answer to reflect the changes you made to your question (in case someone in the future references this question). If you feel my answer correctly resolved your question, please mark it as accepted, which will mark this question as resolved and help future users (and give me rep points :) ). If not, please feel free to reply to these comments.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to concatenate two objects but at least one of them is not of type str, to do so, you should implement the `__str__` method of the User class in which to return the values that represent your class so that you can concatenate it the way you want `dirname + str(username)` its call the `username.__str__` method

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a datatype error or issue. The item you are treating as a String type is really stored as an Object type. Figure out the datatype and then handle it appropriately. You need to convert the type. Convert your username to a string before reading it into the cmd line in your code

I think a change is needed in this line of code: 
cmd = ['some content here', dirname + username + '.p12']

```
class str(object='')
class str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

Return a string version of object. If object is not provided, returns the empty string. Otherwise, the behavior of str() depends on whether encoding or errors is given, as follows.

If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns object.**str**(), which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a **str**() method, then str() falls back to returning repr(object).

If at least one of encoding or errors is given, object should be a bytes-like object (e.g. bytes or bytearray). In this case, if object is a bytes (or bytearray) object, then str(bytes, encoding, errors) is equivalent to bytes.decode(encoding, errors). Otherwise, the bytes object underlying the buffer object is obtained before calling bytes.decode(). See Binary Sequence Types — bytes, bytearray, memoryview and Buffer Protocol for information on buffer objects.

Passing a bytes object to str() without the encoding or errors arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string representation (see also the -b command-line option to Python). For example:

```
str(b'Zoot!')
"b'Zoot!'"
```

For more information on the str class and its methods, see Text Sequence Type — str and the String Methods section below. To output formatted strings, see the Formatted string literals and Format String Syntax sections. In addition, see the Text Processing Services section.

str.format(*args, **kwargs)

Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces {}. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument. Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument.

```
"The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'
```

Information from the following 3 pages should help:

- [Python3 Error: TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699362/python3-error-typeerror-cant-convert-bytes-object-to-str-implicitly)
- http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html
- https://geeksforgeeks.org/important-differences-between-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-with-examples/

*From Sebastian Raschka's site:*

Unicode
Python 2 has ASCII str() types, separate unicode(), but no byte type. (In your case what you used to use as a string, is now being treated like an object.)

Python 3, has Unicode (utf-8) strings, and 2 byte classes: byte and bytearrays.

Python 2:

```
In:  print 'they are really' + b' the same'
Out: they are really the same
```

Python 3:

```
IN:  print('and Python', python_version(), end="")
IN:  print(' also has', type(bytearray(b'bytearrays')))
OUT: and Python 3.4.1 also has <class 'bytearray'>

'note that we cannot add a string' + b'bytes for data'


 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

    <ipython-input-13-d3e8942ccf81> in <module>()
    ----> 1 'note that we cannot add a string' + b'bytes for data'



    TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

*From geeksforgeeks:*

Unicode:

In Python 2, implicit str type is ASCII. But in Python 3.x implicit str type is Unicode.

```
print(type('default string '))
print(type(b'string with b '))

'''
Output in Python 2.x (Bytes is same as str)
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>

Output in Python 3.x (Bytes and str are different)
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
'''
```

Comment: If `username` is a byte array, then I think it can be converted to a string thusly: `username = username.decode('ASCII')`