# Getting error when INSERT into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, html, database, django

```
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE7\xB9\x81\xE9\xAB\x94...' for column 'html' at row 1


def getSource(theurl, moved = 0):
    if moved == 1:
        theurl = urllib2.urlopen(theurl).geturl()
    urlReq = urllib2.Request(theurl)
    urlReq.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
    urlResponse = urllib2.urlopen(urlReq)
    htmlSource = urlResponse.read()
    return htmlSource

new_u = Url(source_url = source_url, source_url_short = source_url_short, source_url_hash = source_url_hash, html = htmlSource)
new_u.save()
```

**Why is this happening?
I am basically downloading URL of a page...and then saving it to a database using Django.**

It only happens sometimes....and sometimes it works fine.

**Edit: it seems like I have to set the database to UTF-8? What is the command to do that?**

Comment: The code where you execute the query please...

Comment: Bobby, the query is new_u, new_u.save() . It's Django query

Comment: @alex: Ohhh...never worked with that system. May best guess is, that you don't escape the html-String, and he's trying to insert 'faulty' values. For PHP the functionality is called mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to ensure proper a string encoding. E.g. the string you provide to django is not UTF-8 encoded and therefore some characters can't be resolved.

Some helpful advice on how to find the encoding of the requested page can be found here: [urllib2 read to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020892/python-urllib2-read-to-unicode)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to go if you want to alter the character set in MySQL.
First is the default of the database, see [MySQL Alter database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-database.html),
and the second is per-table: [MySQL Alter Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html).

The database gives the default charset for, I believe, new tables. This
can be overridden on a per-table basis, which you need to do since you
already have tables. "utf8" is a supported character set.

Also have a look at [Blog about UTF8 with django and MySQL](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/django-and-utf8).