# Why can't I sort this list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
statlist = [('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1), ... ]
sorted(statlist, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

I want to sort it by the integer largest to smallest. In this case, 5 and 66. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be working?"  Please provide the error traceback or specific problem you're *actually* having.

Comment: Also, with three questions of a n00b nature on a Sunday afternoon, I'm guessing this is homework.  Please tag homework clearly.

Comment: I forgot to set the new list to the old one. I thought it worked like the "sort" function.

Comment: @alex: (0) Your two sentences are incompatible ... you can't forget something you didn't know (1) Test your thoughts against (a) the docs (b) simple tests using the interactive interpreter ... often saves asking a question and is much faster (2) consider revisiting `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808567/what-is-the-default-content-type-charset` and finding out what your real problem was.

Comment: @alex: Further thoughts are in an answer (can't format code in comments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sorted` function returns a *new* list so you will need to assign the results of the function like this:

```
new_list = sorted(statlist, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP ask, quoting "the integer largest to smallest".

Comment: Not relating to this, but could any one please tell me what does OP mean ? I have see it in other posts also. Thanks

Comment: Original Poster. Since SO works like a wiki, we refer to the very first user this way, this differentiate what he wrote from what has been corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `.sort` method for in place sorting:

```
statlist = [('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1), ... ]
statlist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

If you do want to use `sorted`, then reassign the variable:

```
statlist = [('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1), ... ]
statlist = sorted(statlist, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

For descending sort, use `reverse`:

```
statlist = [('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1), ... ]
statlist = sorted(statlist, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Then, you'd better use `itemgetter` instead of a `lambda` :

```
import operator
statlist = [('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1), ... ]
statlist = sorted(statlist, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass, key, and reverse to .sort function

```
>>> x.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
>>> x
[('bzs', 66, 1), ('abc', 5, 1)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

for inplace sorting use

```
statlist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

for creating other list, with sorted data use

```
otherlist = sorted( statlist, key=lambda x: x[1] )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
statlist = [('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1), ... ]

# statlist.sort modifiest the statlist, sorted returns a new one
# reverse puts the largest items to the front
statlist.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to alex's comment that he thought that sorted() worked "like the sort function":

If it worked "like the sort function", it is unlikely to have been put in the library.

In any case, there is no sort *function* ... you refer to the sort *method* of list objects.

Simple demonstration using the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> alist = [3, 2, 1]; x = alist.sort(); print x; print alist
None
[1, 2, 3]
>>> alist = [3, 2, 1]; x = sorted(alist); print x; print alist
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Here's a tip: look for patterns and similarities, but always verify your intuitive extrapolations. You might like to apply those ideas to `reverse` and `reversed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = [('xyz', 8, 1), ('abc',5,1), ('bzs',66,1) ]
>>> s = sorted(s, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
>>> s.reverse()
>>> print s
[('bzs', 66, 1), ('xyz', 8, 1), ('abc', 5, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey when ever I am saving something to an array I don't tend to worry about order and then at the end I use `sorted()` for example like this `statlist = sorted(statlist)` and if you wanted it largest to smallest `statlist = sorted(statlist, reverse = True)` That's the simple way of getting largest to smallest!

Example code where I've used this (just an extract)

```
    while i <= math.sqrt(intnum):
        if (intnum % i) == 0:
            numbers.insert(0,i)
            numbers.insert(0,int(intnum/i))
            print(i,":", int(intnum/i))
        i += 1
    numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse = True)
```