# Caching large html fragments in Django and passing them to the template when they contain smart quotes

Tags: python, django

I'm using urllib2 to open and read two external web pages and then saving them to django's internal cache, like so:

```
header = urllib2.urlopen( "http://www.mysite.com/pageheader.html" ).read()
footer = urllib2.urlopen( "http://www.mysite.com/pagefooter.html" ).read()

cache.add( 'header', header )
cache.add( 'footer', footer )
```

I then retrieve these from cache and pass them as template variables:

```
integration = cache.get_many[('header','footer')]
```

The problem appears to be non-ascii characters in one of the fragments preventing it from displaying on the template. These seem to be smart quotes and in vim they appear as:

```
We<92>ve or <93>Tumultuous<94> or just <97>
```

Since I have no access to the remote server, is there a way when grabbing these fragments that I can convert these problems before saving them to cache?

Comment: Which cache backend are you using?

Comment: filesystem caching in django 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Check if urllib2 can properly encode retrieved page, more here:

[urllib2 read to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020892/urllib2-read-to-unicode)