# Cyrillic text extraction in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, localization

I'm using urllib2 to open a russian website and extract text from it. However, instead of coming out as "Беллона" it's coming out as "Áåëëîíà". What's the easiest way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Figure out which encoding the webpage uses (probably utf-8 or ISO 8859-5), and convert your text to unicode like this:

```
ustring = unicode(read_string, encoding=...)
```

If you need to determine the encoding of a webpage dynamically, see [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020892/urllib2-read-to-unicode)

Comment: Thanks! 'windows-1251' was the encoding that ended up working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
doc = urllib.open('http://yandex.ru').read()
doc = doc.decode('utf-8')
```

That's all ;)