# Converting html source content into readable format with Python 2.x

Tags: python, html

Python 2.7

I have a program that gets video titles from the source code of a webpage but the titles are encoded in some HTML format.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.unquote('&pound;')
'&pound;'
```

So that didn't work...
Then I tried:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('&pound;')
u'\xa3'
```

as you can see that doesn't work either nor any combination of the two.

I managed to find out that `'&pound;'` is an HTML character entity name. The '\xa3' I wasn't able to find out.

Does anyone know how to do this, how to convert HTML content into a readable format in python?

Comment: Check out BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&pound;` is the html character entity for the [POUND SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm), which is unicode character U+00A3.  You can see this if you print it:

```
>>> print u'\xa3'
£
```

When you use `unescape()`, you converted the character entity to it's native unicode character, which is what `u'\xa3'` means--a single U+00A3 unicode character.

If you want to encode this into another format (e.g. utf-8), you would do so with the `encode` method of strings:

```
>>> u'\xa3'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc2\xa3'
```

You get a two-byte string representing the single "POUND SIGN" character.

I suspect that you are a bit unclear about how string encodings work in general. You need to convert your string from bytes to unicode (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1020931/1002469) for one way to do that with urllib2), then unescape the html, then (possibly) convert the unicode into whatever output encoding you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't that work?

```
In [1]: s = u'\xa3'

In [2]: s
Out[2]: u'\xa3'

In [3]: print s
£
```

When it comes to unescaping html entities I always used: http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html.

Answer (score 1):

The video title strings use [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to encode special characters, such as ampersands and pound signs.

The `\xa3` is the Python [Unicode character literal](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) for the [pound sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign#Codepoints) (£).  In your example, Python is displaying the [__repr__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) of a Unicode string, which is why you see the escapes.  If you print this string, you can see it represents the pound sign:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('&pound;')
u'\xa3'
>>> print h.unescape('&pound;')
£
```

Answer (score 0):

lxml, BeautifulSoup or PyQuery does the job pretty well. Or [combination](https://github.com/starenka/emery/blob/master/emery/page.py#L88) of these ;)