# HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape() doesn't work

Tags: python, html, unicode

I would like to convert HTML entities back to its human readable format, e.g. `'&pound;'` to '£', `'&deg;'` to '°' etc.

I've read several posts regarding this question

[Converting html source content into readable format with Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704302/converting-html-source-content-into-readable-format-with-python-2-x)

[Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

[Convert XML/HTML Entities into Unicode String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)

and according to them, I chose to use the undocumented function unescape(), but it doesn't work for me...

My code sample is like:

```
import HTMLParser

htmlParser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
decoded = htmlParser.unescape('&copy; 2013')
print decoded
```

When I ran this python script, the output is still:

```
&copy; 2013
```

instead of

```
© 2013
```

I'm using Python 2.X, working on Windows 7 and Cygwin console. I googled and didn't find any similar problems..Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I have tried calling it from the command line and the IDLE, and it does work for me (Python 2.7 on Windows 8).

Answer (score 8):

Apparently `HTMLParser.unescape` was a [bit more primitive](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.5/Lib/HTMLParser.py#l361) before [Python 2.6](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/HTMLParser.py#l365).

Python 2.5:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape('&copy;')
'&copy;'
```

Python 2.6/2.7:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape('&copy;')
u'\xa9'
```

UPDATE: Python 3.4+:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&copy;')
'©'
```

See the [2.5 implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.5/Lib/HTMLParser.py#l361) vs the [2.6 implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/HTMLParser.py#l365) / [2.7 implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/HTMLParser.py#l447)

Comment: it is `html.unescape()` in Python 3.4+

Comment: *in Python 3.4-3.8

Answer (score 6):

Starting in python 3.9 using `HTMLParser()unescape(<str>)` will result in the error `AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'`

You can update it to:

```
import html
html.unescape(<str>)
```

Comment: Exatcly what I was looking for python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml) lists some solutions, here's one of them:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape

html_escape_table = {
    '"': "&quot;",
    "'": "&apos;",
    "©": "&copy;"
    # etc...
}
html_unescape_table = {v:k for k, v in html_escape_table.items()}

def html_unescape(text):
    return unescape(text, html_unescape_table)
```

Not the prettiest thing though, since you would have to list each escaped symbol manually.

EDIT:

How about this?

```
import htmllib

def unescape(s):
    p = htmllib.HTMLParser(None)
    p.save_bgn()
    p.feed(s)
    return p.save_end()
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. But the content of my html page is unknown, so unless I listed all the html special characters...